# What is a correct term for object decomposition via message bus?

Tags: architecture

Big applications contains lots of objects that are somehow connected to each other. There are direct connections than one object somehow gets handle to another object (for example, using singleton) and calling it's methods. There are function level or interface level delegation. There are aggregation than some objects are childs of parent object that calls childs methods etc etc.

One of advanced decompositions in software architecture is a message bus, where objects register itself to some singleton "message bus" provider and send message using it. Any object can send any message via message bus and objects that are subscribed for this kind of message will receive it.

What is the correct term for such architecture? I have a few candidates, but they seems not very good:

**Message Bus**: Exactly the same thing i'm talking about but for communications between different applications, not between parts of same application.

**OSGI**: Used for communication between application parts but main focus is dynamic loading, starting and stopping of such parts, versioning etc.

**Middleware**: Like a "message bus", this term describes an architectural solution for communication between applications, with focus on communication between different physical 
computers via network.

Anyone knows a good term that defines an architecture i described above? So if i enter it in google i will get relevant results, not something like "buy our middleware for your business aplications integration!" :).

Comment: Aren't you talking about the observer pattern? Or perhaps you're looking for an event bus/event broker?

Comment: @alexn It seems that "event bus" is a correct term. Please answer question so i can accept answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:

It seems that you're looking for an event bus. A event bus is basically an in-process message bus.